# Vector Layer Label is truncating/rounding value

Tags: openlayers-2

I cannot figure out how to keep OpenLayers from truncating my vector layer label. For example, I have a value of 0.00 and want to show both significant digits, but it always makes it an integer 0. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the default implementation of `OpenLayers.Style.createLiteral`:

```
OpenLayers.Style.createLiteral = function(value, context, feature, property) {
    if (typeof value == "string" && value.indexOf("${") != -1) {
        value = OpenLayers.String.format(value, context, [feature, property]);
        value = (isNaN(value) || !value) ? value : parseFloat(value);
    }
    return value;
};
```

As you can see, if `value` is a number it will parse it as float which trims trailing zeroes, etc. One way to fix it is to override this method in your application, for example removing that entire line in your custom version. This way the string would be always displayed as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your label value is a number object (if not, convert it to numbers), then you can just use function `toFixed(2)`, and it will convert your numbers to strings with two decimal places. However, in such way all you numbers will be converted to have 2 decimal places, as the number shown in the picture, 0.2 will become 0.20, 2.9 will be 2.90. But of course you can program it to be anyway as you like.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I actually tried that way, and it was still truncating the label. I ended up taking kryger's suggestion and overrode the createLiteral function which did the trick.